# webos image not working on raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, image, win32diskimager

on: http://build.webos-ports.org/webosose/raspberrypi3/ There are several .rpi-sdimg files for raspberry pi 3.

I have flashed a couple of them on to a SD card but when I power them up in my raspberry pi 3 the only thing I see is the multicolored square for a couple seconds then a black screen and my tv says no device on input.

Does anyone know what I am supposed to do with this .rpi-sdimg file? I am used to flashing .img files so I am unfamiliar with what to do. I have been flashing them with Win32DiskImager with no luck. I tried to build the image in linux but ran into trouble in not behing able to apt-get makeinf and chrpath so I had to resort to trying a pre-built image in windows. Any tips on how to get this working would make my aunt very happy. I plan to use it to make her std tvs smart tvs so she can cut the chord on her cable bill and save a little money. thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: How is your tv connected? Have you tried a monitor with HDMI?

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Why won't it work on the TV? Also do  you know why it doesn't include the app center? I need to load youtube TV, Netflix, Prive Video, and Plex the same way my LG tv with WebOS does.

Comment: This is for a project for my Aunt to turn all of her std TVs into smart TVs since she is getting internet for the first time so that she can ditch her cable subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run that stuff on a 3B+ as there isn't a version built since 2018. It won't have the kernel and bootcode for your hardware version.

You'll need to ask the developer(s) what their plans are to support the latest version and whether their project is still alive. You could also ask if there's any way to upgrade their OS by booting it on an older Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It isn't a 3B+ it is a Rpi3.